# Spring cloud sleuth with Spring data jpa

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth

We are trying to implement Spring cloud sleuth with Zipkin in our project and wanted to know if Spring cloud sleuth will support DB calls with Spring data JPA.

I want to trace the time taken for DB calls just like service calls

When I make a service call with RestTemplate, that gets sent to zipkin and I am able to see that on the dashboard

But DB interactions with Spring data jpa is not getting displayed in Zipkin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the new Dalston feature of using annotations on Spring Data repositories. You can check out this for more info http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/spring-cloud-sleuth.html#_managing_spans_with_annotations

Comment: Thanks! But doesn't that mean we have to add the annotation for every JPA interface method. Is there any other way?

Comment: You can write an aspect to wrap all of these. I don't actually think it's sth that you'd want to do though. Are you really interested in tracing everything?

Comment: I guess using class level annotations (which isn't currently possible) would be handy for such case: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues/772

Comment: Yeah, currently I've removed it from classes. We might consider adding it in the future.